# Creating dynamic associative array in configuration

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, yaml

I got yml configuration like this:

```
test_array:
    dynamic_key:
        - 'this_is_value'
        - 'it_is_also_a_value'
    second_dynamic_key:
        - 'yop, value'
        - 'another value'
```

After configuration, I want to get an array like this:

```
$iNeedToGetArrayLikeThis = [
    'dynamic_key' => [
        'this_is_value',
        'it_is_also_a_value'
    ],
    'second_dynamic_key' => [
        'yop, value',
        'another value'
    ]
];
```

but I get:

```
$whatIGet = [
    [
        'dynamic_key' => [
            'this_is_value',
            'it_is_also_a_value'
        ],
        'second_dynamic_key' => [
            'yop, value',
            'another value'
        ]
    ],
];
```

I tried using `->useAttributeAsKey()` but that didn't worked either.

My code configuration code:

```
->children()
   ->arrayNode('test_array')
       ->ignoreExtraKeys(true)
          ->arrayPrototype()
             ->prototype('scalar')
             ->end()
           ->end()
       ->end()
   ->end()
->end()
```

Comment: Can you just use `$whatIGet[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as simple:

```
test_array:
    - dynamic_key: ['this_is_value', 'it_is_also_a_value']
    - second_dynamic_key: ['yop, value', 'another value']
```

[demo](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=test_array%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20dinamic_key%3A%20%5B%27this_is_value%27%2C%20%27it_is_also_a_value%27%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20second_dinamic_key%3A%20%5B%27yop%2C%20value%27%2C%20%27another%20value%27%5D&type=json)

or

```
test_array:
    - dynamic_key: 
        - 'this_is_value'
        - 'it_is_also_a_value'
    - second_dynamic_key: 
        - 'yop, value'
        - 'another value'
```

[demo](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=test_array%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20dinamic_key%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%27this_is_value%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%27it_is_also_a_value%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20second_dinamic_key%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%27yop%2C%20value%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20%27another%20value%27&type=json)